# Динамическое создание и заполнение таблиц JS

Tags: javascript, html

html страница:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
    <title>Отчёт</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="layout">
      <div id = "divShow"><strong>Просмотр записей</strong></div>
        <img src="../img/reel-of-film.png" alt="reel-of-film-image"               class="reel-of-film-image">
      </div>

    <script src="../js/singletonlist.controller.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

singletonlist.controller.js:

```
(function() {
  var results = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('results'));

  var newElem=document.createElement("table");
  var newRow=newElem.insertRow(1);
  var newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
  newCell.width="200";
  newCell.innerHTML="строка 1 столбец 1";   
})();
```

Есть объект:

```
var userData = {
  login: formElements.login.value,
  password: formElements.password.value,
  typeOfTVShow: formElements.typeOfTVShow.value,
  tvShows: [],
  isCinemaddict: formElements.isCinemaddict.value,
  comment: formElements.comment.value
};
```

Массив с этими объектами хранится в localStorage, как для каждого объекта из localStorage сделать свою таблицу на html странице?

Comment: login/password в localStorage? Для разных пользователей?

Comment: да, есть разные пользователи

Comment: э-э-э, Вас не смущает, что на клиенте хранятся пароли разных пользователей?

Comment: не смущает, так как это поле относительное и роли никакой не играет, отчет должен будет представлять лишь login, typeOfTVShow,  tvShows,  isCinemaddict, comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> поле относительное и роли никакой не играет

Ну тогда

```
var results = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('results'));

for (var iter = 0; iter < results.length; iter++) {
  var newElem=document.createElement("table");
  var newRow=newElem.insertRow(0);
  var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  newCell.width="200";
  newCell.innerHTML="строка 1 столбец 1: " + results[iter].login;

  document.getElementById("divShow").appendChild(newElem);
}
```