# Динамическое заполнение таблицы JS

Tags: javascript, angular2

Как с помощью javascript или angular2 можно динамически заполнить данными из массива уже сформированную на странице статическую таблицу?

Грубо говоря, на странице будет пустая статическая таблица, куда по клику нужно заносить данные в столбцы.

Спасибо!

Comment: Писать обработчик на кнопку "Добавить" и заносить. Какой вопрос, такой ответ.

Comment: Связанный: [Динамическое создание и заполнение таблиц JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591033/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86-js)

Comment: Без вашего куска кода, скорее всего получите лишь теоретический ответ

Comment: У меня кода пока нет. Я пока концептуально не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Попытка ведь не пытка. Тем более если Вы не писали код, нафига Вам ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По клику:
1 увеличивать счетчик - это будет индекс элемента массива.
2 в innerHTML кликнутой ячейки занести значение элемента массива.